# How to connect hyperledger composer rest server to own created authentication?

Tags: rest, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, loopback

I have a node.js application that authenticate users and generates token. My question is:

- 1. How to configure my own created authentication to
     composer-rest-server?
- 2. How to configure the environment variable
     **COMPOSER_PROVIDERS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Using JSON Web Token (JWT)

2) Environment variables that the composer rest server runs in a multi-user mode, and allows authentication based on passport-jwt

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "jwt": {
    "provider": "jwt",
    "module": "/home/composer/node_modules/custom-jwt.js",
    "secretOrKey": "gSi4WmttWuvy2ewoTGooigPwSDoxwZOy",
    "authScheme": "saml",
    "successRedirect": "/",
    "failureRedirect":"/"
    }
}
```